# Сохранение композитного объекта в базе

Tags: c#, entity-framework

В домене приложения есть объект/entity Place (Место) и есть у него среди других value object'ов – координаты на яндекс:карте (x,y и zoom карты):

```
public class Place
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public YandexMapPoint Point { get; set; }
}

public class YandexMapPoint
{
    public float X { get; set; }

    public float Y { get; set; }

    public byte Zoom { get; set; }
}
```

При этом я хочу, чтобы в базе это хранилось в одной таблице с полями Id, Title, x, y, zoom – и при чтении из базы разворачивалось обратно в доменный объект. А при сохранении доменного объекта – наоборот, складировалось в одну таблицу.

Я использую EF (EF6 или Core, не принципиально) Code First.

Как мне описать подобную структуру на уровне работы с базой данных?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конечно, это возможно. Создавая новый проект, я думал, придётся либо с атрибутами помудрить, либо флюэнт-интерфейс заюзать.

Но для начала я создал заготовку следующего вида:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConAppEF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var context = new MyContext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(context.Places.Count());
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }
    }

    public class Place
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public YandexMapPoint Point { get; set; }
    }

    public class YandexMapPoint
    {
        public float X { get; set; }
        public float Y { get; set; }
        public byte Zoom { get; set; }
    }
}
```

После запуска было создана БД с такой таблицей:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Places] (
    [Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Point_X]    REAL           NOT NULL,
    [Point_Y]    REAL           NOT NULL,
    [Point_Zoom] TINYINT        NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Places] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Даже не пришлось ничего делать.

Comment: Ха, а я уже полез вспоминать что я помню про TPH и прочие мудрёные темы ))