# Entity Framework Core хранение в таблице своих типов данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Можно ли как нибудь добиться сохранение в БД(MySQL) специфичных типов данных которые не поддерживает БД. Т.е типа Vector3, List и.т.д

Моя модель выглядит так:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id{get;set;}
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public Vector3 Position {get;set;} //при миграции выдает ошибку.
}
```

Использую Entity Framework Core 2.0

Comment: Сериализуйте (в XML, в JSON...) и сохраняйте.

Comment: Если вам нужно эту информацию просто хранить (без отдельных таблиц, сложных запросов по этим критериям и связям) в базе, то можно просто сериализовать в какой-нибудь формат (бинарный, JSON, XML и т.п.).

Comment: Создавайте отдельную сущность и храните ее в отдельной таблице, после получения создавайте из этой сущности уже нужную (Vector3 или что хотите). Преимущество перед хранением сериализованного объекта - можно осуществлять поиск по отдельным свойствам.

Comment: Покажите класс Vector3

Comment: Используйте Json + NotMapped: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/500734/213987

Comment: Возможно вам поможет [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/806811/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5)

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - можешь преобразовывать данные в формат JSON, сохранять их. При выборке - декодировать данные.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx